# Maven not able to find 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, jdbc

I have Spring Boot application that I try to connect to my local database. I can run the file as a regular Java file and it connects to the database with no error. However, when I run `mvn clean spring-boot:run` it prints the following output.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

In my pom.xml I have

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

I checked the Maven dependencies and postgresql-42.2.19.jar is in there.

In my application-default.yml I have as

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pharmacy
    username: ****
    password: ****
    platform: postgresql
    initialize: false
    continue-on-error: false
```

This is suggested by https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-failed-to-configure-data-source

Comment: any reason to have `application-default.yml` instead of `application.yml`

Comment: It was for different builds. `application-default.yml` for local and `application-production.yml` is for prod environment. But renaming to `applicaiton.yml` solved my problem. Than you. Could you post an answer so I can accept the answer pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having database properties in `application-default.yml` which only will be activated when you use "default" spring profile.

So, either use "default" spring profile (not maven profile) or move the properties to `application.yml` which will be used by default whether you use any profiles or not.